# Help eclipse find my enum values?

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

I'm having trouble getting Eclipse to notice the enum values when using code completion. The `XmlDataDefitions` class provides the schema of data that will be parsed from XML. But I cannot seem to call `XmlDataDefitions.xmlTagGroups.xmlLocationList.values().YYZ` or `XmlDataDefinitions.xmlTagGroups.xmlLocationList.XmlTags.id`. Code completion & the compiler do not seem to have the `XmlTags` visible.

For some reason Eclipse is unable to list off the `XmlTags` (enum values) in code completion. Ideally I'd like to call `XmlDataDefinitions.xmlTagGroups.xmlLocationList.(something).XmlTags.id`...

```
public class XmlDataDefinitions {

    public static enum XmlTags {
        id,device_id,screen_name,
        title,message,
        lat_coords,lng_coords,address_string,
        loc_seen,account_pic,
        from_device_id,to_device_id,
        from_screen_name,to_screen_name,
        date,
    }

    public static enum xmlTagGroups {
        xmlLocationList(XmlTags.id, XmlTags.device_id, XmlTags.title, XmlTags.message, XmlTags.lat_coords, XmlTags.lng_coords, XmlTags.loc_seen),
        xmlMemberList(XmlTags.id, XmlTags.device_id, XmlTags.screen_name, XmlTags.address_string, XmlTags.lat_coords, XmlTags.lng_coords, XmlTags.account_pic),
        xmlChatList(XmlTags.id, XmlTags.from_device_id, XmlTags.to_device_id, XmlTags.from_screen_name, XmlTags.to_screen_name, XmlTags.message),

        xmlLocationMessage(XmlTags.id, XmlTags.device_id, XmlTags.message,XmlTags.screen_name),     
        xmlChatMessage(XmlTags.id, XmlTags.from_device_id, XmlTags.to_device_id, XmlTags.from_screen_name, XmlTags.to_screen_name, XmlTags.message, XmlTags.date),

        ;

        public XmlTags[] tags;

        private xmlTagGroups (XmlTags ... tags){
            this.tags = tags;
        }

        public XmlTags[] getTags(){
            return this.tags;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reestarting eclipse? Sometimes it messes up.

Comment: I just did that and it did not help. How should I actually access the enum values (with code completion) in XmlDataDefinitions.XmlTagGroups.xmlLocationList?

Comment: Is the last comma in `XmlTags` just a mistype?

Comment: No, its there to provide the enum constructor after the enum field definitions.

Comment: @Kevin: pls, show the full code. I have doubts that this one can be compiled.

Comment: That is the entire class, you should be able to compile it without issue. I'm still looking for a way to actually have visibility of XmlDataDefinitions.XmlTagGroups.xmlLocationList.XmlTag.id in eclipse's code completion.

Comment: What's the package declaration?

Comment: package com.AtClass.MessageMarker;

Comment: And what is the path to the compiled class files?

Comment: C:\Users\Kevin\workspace\MessageMarker\bin

Comment: What exactly do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your enums are static inner classes and unbelievably the enum values are *not visible* inside the containing class!

To fix, you need to static import the enum class entries into the vary class they are defined in, like this:

```
import static com.mycompany.mypackage.XmlDataDefinitions.XmlTags.*;
```

Then you'll be able to use `device_id` (for example) without `XmlTags.` qualification.

Crazy, I know, but there it is. Once you add the static import, Eclipse will code-complete them as expected.

The other fix is to put the enums into their own class, but like you I usually prefer to bundle my 
enums into the class that uses/owns them (to avoid class bloat - where it makes sense).

Comment: Thanks for your response but it still does not work. You mention to import them 'into the vary class they are defined in'. The class already had an import for them: import com.AtClass.MessageMarker.XmlDataDefinitions.XmlTags; Replacing it with the import above didn't help. I also tried importing it in the class that will use them. I'm still not able to call XmlDataDefinitions.xmlTagGroups.xmlLocationList. and have it complete the tages defined in that enum.

Comment: The static import definitely works (I use it all the time). Do you have `Project > Build automatically` ticked? Try forcing a build and try closing Eclipse and reopening it. Sometimes it just "loses the plot".

Comment: One sec, so how am I supposed to be able to access it? As xmlTagGroups.xmlLocationsList.device_id for example? I tried cleaning the project and restarting eclipse. Still no dice. The code completion fails to show any of the contents of the enum at xmlTagGroups.xmlLocationList.

Comment: @Kevin: the important part is the 'static' in the import statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure I know what you try to achieve. But maybe you want to write expressions like theese?

```
import test.XmlTagGroup;
import test.XmlTagGroup.XmlTag;

public class TestIt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(XmlTagGroup.xmlChatList.tags.contains(XmlTag.id));
        System.out.println("");
        for (XmlTag tag : XmlTagGroup.xmlChatList.tags)
            System.out.println(tag);
    }
}
```

to get

```
true

id
message
from_device_id
to_device_id
from_screen_name
to_screen_name
```

If so, try it like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public enum XmlTagGroup {

    xmlLocationList(XmlTag.id, XmlTag.device_id, XmlTag.title, XmlTag.message, XmlTag.lat_coords, XmlTag.lng_coords,
            XmlTag.loc_seen),
    xmlMemberList(XmlTag.id, XmlTag.device_id, XmlTag.screen_name, XmlTag.address_string, XmlTag.lat_coords,
            XmlTag.lng_coords, XmlTag.account_pic),
    xmlChatList(XmlTag.id, XmlTag.from_device_id, XmlTag.to_device_id, XmlTag.from_screen_name, XmlTag.to_screen_name,
            XmlTag.message),
    xmlLocationMessage(XmlTag.id, XmlTag.device_id, XmlTag.message, XmlTag.screen_name),
    xmlChatMessage(XmlTag.id, XmlTag.from_device_id, XmlTag.to_device_id, XmlTag.from_screen_name,
            XmlTag.to_screen_name, XmlTag.message, XmlTag.date),
    ;

    public static enum XmlTag {
        id, device_id, screen_name, title, message, lat_coords, lng_coords, address_string, loc_seen, account_pic,
        from_device_id, to_device_id, from_screen_name, to_screen_name, date,
    }

    public SortedSet<XmlTag> tags;

    private XmlTagGroup(XmlTag... tags) {
        this.tags = Collections.unmodifiableSortedSet(new TreeSet<XmlTag>(Arrays.asList(tags)));
    }

}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this [before](http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-building-m2.html) where the path to the compiled class is greater than [259](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#maxpath) characters on Windows XP/2000. In this case I end up with class not found errors for static inner classes which have a path that exceeds this depth. These kind of issues are quite common when working with complex XSD schemas and generated classes.

Consider using shorter classnames/packages and relocating your source code to somewhere closer to the root of the directory structure.